# Spring Boot AngularJs Application: angular-bootstrap.css generation using wro4j-maven-plugin Fails

Tags: java, angularjs, maven, spring-boot, wro4j

I am following [the part 1 of this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_spring_and_angular_js_a_secure_single_page_application). I have reached this section "**Loading a Dynamic Resource from Angular**". As per the tutorial instructions, when I build the aplication using maven `mvn clean package`, the wro4j-maven-plugin fails to generate the angular-bootstrap.css but the angular-bootstrap.js is generated successfully. I am getting the following warnings in the mvn console

```
$ mvn clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building demo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ myDemo ---
[INFO] Deleting E:\workspace\demo\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- wro4j-maven-plugin:1.8.0:run (default) @ myDemo ---
[INFO] E:\workspace\demo/src/main/wro
[INFO] Executing the mojo:
[INFO] Wro4j Model path: E:\workspace\demo\src\main\wro\wro.xml
[INFO] targetGroups: null
[INFO] minimize: true
[INFO] ignoreMissingResources: null
[INFO] parallelProcessing: false
[INFO] buildDirectory: E:\workspace\demo\target
[INFO] destinationFolder: E:\workspace\demo\target
[INFO] jsDestinationFolder: E:\workspace\demo\target\classes\static\js
[INFO] cssDestinationFolder: E:\workspace\demo\target\classes\static\css
[INFO] The following groups will be processed: [angular-bootstrap]
[INFO] folder: E:\workspace\demo\target\classes\static\css
[INFO] processing group: angular-bootstrap.css
[WARNING] Less warnings are:
[WARNING] 0:2 Cannot link source map. Css result location is not know and could not be deduced from input less source..
[INFO] folder: E:\workspace\demo\target\classes\static\js
[INFO] processing group: angular-bootstrap.js
[INFO] file size: angular-bootstrap.js -> 240652 bytes
[INFO] E:\workspace\demo\target\classes\static\js\angular-bootstrap.js (240652 bytes)
```

As a result of this, when I run the application, I am getting 404 for angular-bootstrap.css. Please let me know where I am going wrong. Please find the relevant configurations below.

**/demo/src/main/wro/wro.xml**

```
<groups xmlns="http://www.isdc.ro/wro">
  <group name="angular-bootstrap">
    <css>webjar:bootstrap/3.3.7-1/less/bootstrap.less</css>   
    <css>file:@project.basedir@/src/main/wro/main.less</css>
    <js>webjar:jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js</js>
    <js>webjar:angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js</js>
    <js>webjar:angularjs/1.4.9/angular-route.min.js</js>
    <js>webjar:angularjs/1.4.9/angular-cookies.min.js</js>
   </group>
</groups>
```

**/demo/src/main/wro/wro.properties**

```
preProcessors=lessCssImport
postProcessors=less4j,jsMin
```

**/demo/src/main/wro/main.less** [Actually this file is empty.]

**/demo/pom.xml**

```
<build>

  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>generate-resources</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <wroManagerFactory>ro.isdc.wro.maven.plugin.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory</wroManagerFactory>
        <cssDestinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/classes/static/css</cssDestinationFolder>
        <jsDestinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/classes/static/js</jsDestinationFolder>
        <wroFile>${basedir}/src/main/wro/wro.xml</wroFile>
        <extraConfigFile>${basedir}/src/main/wro/wro.properties</extraConfigFile>
        <contextFolder>${basedir}/src/main/wro</contextFolder>
      </configuration>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
          <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
          <artifactId>angularjs</artifactId>
          <version>1.4.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
          <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>

</build>
```

I am using

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_111
spring-boot 1.4.2.RELEASE
OS : windows 10
```

### Edit 1

I tried with --debug flag in mvn. I got this debug message

```
[DEBUG] Created file: angular-bootstrap.css
[DEBUG] No content found for group: angular-bootstrap.css
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue got fixed after changing the version of bootstrap in pom.xml as follows

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
  <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.7-1</version>
</dependency>
```

Now the angular-bootstrap.css is getting generated successfully.

Comment: I have the same issue but this didn't resovle it :-(

Comment: Did you get any additional info about the issue by enabling the `mvn --debug` flag?

Comment: In order this sollution to work you have to update wro.xml as well, update <css> tag value - 
`<css>webjar:bootstrap/3.3.7-1/less/bootstrap.less</css>`

Answer (score 1):

I hit this same snag following that tutorial and got past it by copying the wro4j `<plugin>...</plugin>` block from the `pom.xml` AND the `wro.xml` file contents from the github project linked on the demo page, rather than using the code examples on that page.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can find an updated version on the github repositry published along with the solution (I also published a pull request for that matter).

Problem is, I find it breaks the DRY principle, as they repeat jquery, bootstrap and angularjs versions.

Three steps to correct the problem:

1. Defining versions in one place (Maven properties element):

   ```
   <properties>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
       <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
       <java.version>1.8</java.version>
       <wro4j.version>1.8.0</wro4j.version>
       <bootstrap.version>3.3.7-1</bootstrap.version>
       <angularjs.version>1.5.9</angularjs.version>
       <jquery.version>3.1.1-1</jquery.version>
   </properties>
   ```
2. Reusing the generated-resources folders to allow IntelliJ and other IDEs to resolve the path for the generated files, in the plugin configuration:

   ```
   <build>

       <resources>
           <resource>
               <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
           </resource>
           <resource>
               <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources</directory>
           </resource>
       </resources>

       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <!-- Serves *only* to filter the wro.xml so it can get an absolute
                         path for the project -->
                       <id>copy-resources</id>
                       <phase>validate</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                       </goals>
                       <configuration>
                           <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/wro</outputDirectory>
                           <resources>
                               <resource>
                                   <directory>src/main/wro</directory>
                                   <filtering>true</filtering>
                               </resource>
                           </resources>
                       </configuration>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>

           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           </plugin>

           <plugin>
               <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
               <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>${wro4j.version}</version>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <phase>compile</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>run</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
               <configuration>
                   <wroManagerFactory>ro.isdc.wro.maven.plugin.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory
                   </wroManagerFactory>
                   <cssDestinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources/static/css
                   </cssDestinationFolder>
                   <jsDestinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources/static/js</jsDestinationFolder>
                   <wroFile>${project.build.directory}/wro/wro.xml</wroFile>
                   <extraConfigFile>${project.build.directory}/wro/wro.properties</extraConfigFile>
                   <contextFolder>${project.build.directory}/wro</contextFolder>
               </configuration>
               <dependencies>
                   <dependency>
                       <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                       <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
                       <version>${jquery.version}</version>
                   </dependency>
                   <dependency>
                       <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                       <artifactId>angularjs</artifactId>
                       <version>${angularjs.version}</version>
                   </dependency>
                   <dependency>
                       <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                       <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
                       <version>${bootstrap.version}</version>
                   </dependency>
               </dependencies>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
   ```
3. Take advantage of Spring properties filtering in wro.xml:

   ```
   <groups xmlns="http://www.isdc.ro/wro">
     <group name="angular-bootstrap">
       <css>webjar:bootstrap/@bootstrap.version@/less/bootstrap.less</css>
       <css>file:src/main/wro/main.less</css>
       <js>webjar:jquery/@jquery.version@/jquery.min.js</js>
       <js>webjar:angularjs/@angularjs.version@/angular.min.js</js>
       <js>webjar:angularjs/@angularjs.version@/angular-route.min.js</js>
       <js>webjar:angularjs/@angularjs.version@/angular-cookies.min.js</js>
      </group>
   </groups>
   ```